# Remove "Chrome Apps" From Xubuntu Menu

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, google-chrome, xfce

Earlier today I installed Google Chrome only to realize that I needed to uninstall it for reasons I won't get into here, so I removed Google Chrome and got Mozilla Firefox back. Before I uninstalled Google Chrome, I downloaded an app from the Chrome Web Store that runs in its own window (not in Google Chrome) that added Chrome Apps into my Xubuntu menu so I can access it. I restarted my computer after the uninstallation, but the Chrome Apps submenu is still in my Xfce menu! I thought this was a problem with a file Google Chrome left behind, so I reinstalled Google Chrome just so I could type `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable`, which should have deleted some of its files, but that didn't help at all but Google Chrome was still removed from my system like I wanted, including the Chrome App I downloaded. The links in the Chrome Apps menu are broken (like they should be because Google Chrome and the Chrome Apps were removed), but the folder is still there. How do I remove the Chrome Apps menu (or submenu or folder or whatever you call it) from the Xfce menu? Below is a screenshot of this problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Come on. Is there a "menu" folder in the system that determines what is in the menu, because if there is, say so!

Comment: Chrome Apps does not display the Google Chrome logo because Google Chrome was removed, should that help you.

Comment: Check `/usr/share/applications/` (unlikely) and `~/.share/applications/` (likely) for the menu entry.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Chrome installs app shortcuts to `$HOME/.local/share/applications`. You should be able to delete all residual launcher entries with the following command:

```
rm $HOME/.local/share/applications/chrome-*.desktop
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked instantly and solved my problem. (I will award you the bounty in 21 hours, I can't right now.)

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste Glad I could help :).

Comment: this still works on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Easy method:

- Open chrome browser
- Open extension(Manage extension) in it
- Go down and check that electro application
- You will get an option to remove it

Harsh method:

```
rm $HOME/.local/share/applications/chrome-*.desktop
```